# Most stable gcc/g++ version to date

Tags: gcc, g++

I want to know which gcc/g++ version released is the most stable to date? I had an impression that gcc version 2.95 was the most stable but a few peers told me that gcc 3.x versions are now the most stable.

Comment: I would like to ask the same question now..

Answer (score 4):

The 2.95 branch [hasn't had an update in over ten years](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.95/). I certainly wouldn't be using it for *anything* voluntarily. Use whatever is the latest available for your system unless you have specific knowledge of a need to use something else (a vague "impression" is not specific knowledge, actual bugs and specific compatibility problems are).

Even 3.x is rapidly aging. There is no general reason not to use 4.x.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My need is that I want to build one linux package which shall be deployed and run on all the linux platform, namely rgel5,6 and sles 10,11. I faced an issue while deploying a package built on rhel5 when i executed the same on sles10. (ABI incompatibilities). hcnce i am looking to build a package with lowest version of gcc and deploy it everywhere. JFYI, I am not going to use any advanced compiler features. The aim is to just have a 'compile once, run everywhere software for linux.

Comment: @jdoe: The only completely reliable way to avoid ABI incompatibilities between Linux distributions is to statically link your binaries. Compiler version has little or nothing to do with that at all. I'm also entirely unsure what you think "advanced compiler features" means -- 2.95 isn't even remotely _standards compliant_, especially for C++. You're sticking yourself in the dark ages for no reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The only gcc versions that are actively worked on - i.e. debugged and stabilized are gcc-4.n where n > 3 these days.  Use the gcc-4.* series.  Even cygwin and mingw are off gcc-3.* these days.

Answer (score 0):

[GCC 4.6.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-10/msg00486.html) has been released recently, on 27 Oct 2011.

And chosing a specific version of GCC is not a guarantee that your binary will work on all linux-es you want, because distributions may have different versions of the C++ standard libraries.

I'll recommend not using something older than GCC 4.5, and preferably 4.6. However, you might want to use the version used to compile your linux distribution.